# Is there realised solutions to unpack `stdin` as arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

I would like to have the option to pass positional arguments via `stdin`. I have written my own `argparse.Action` subclass to overwhelm the problem, that does work, but it would be desirable to evade reinventing the wheel. Are there realised third-party or built-in solutions to automatically handle a hyphen as a source of the argument set?

My class:

```py
class ExtendStdin(Action):
    def __call__(
        self,
        parser: ArgumentParser,
        namespace: Namespace,
        values: Sequence[str | Path],
        option_string: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        if "-" in values:
            if len(values) == 1:
                content = sys.stdin.read()
                sep = "\0" if "\0" in content else "\n"
                values = list(map(existing_filepath, content.split(sep)))
            else:
                raise ValueError("Specification of both stdin & paths is not allowed.")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

`existing_filepath` is the function checking that a file path exists.

I am aware of the `argparse.FileType` feature, allowing me to convert a hyphen to the default `stdin` or `stdout`. But this treats a hyphen as one file-like argument instead of the source of an argument set.

---

### Update 15.09.23

The question touches upon `argparse` extensions or packages, adding auxiliary functionality for parsing arguments.
I know `shlex` package, that was suggested in the comments, allowing to handle strings as a set of shell arguments and vice versa. Howbeit, the question is not about how to split the standard input stream.

Comment: Use `shlex.parse()` to split the input into a list, then pass that as the argument list to `argparse()`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is also a solution. But the question was about existing extensions of `argparse` or additional parsing tools. For instance, my class also splits the standard input stream into arguments. Although, I am interested to know is there anything else or should I use my custom solution and this is normal and okay?

Comment: `argparse` will parse any list of arguments. Why do you need an "additional package" just to split stdin into a list?

Comment: And requests for library recommendations are also off-topic.

Comment: @Barmar I am sorry for the off-topic! I too often reinvent the wheel.